# Creating a Spark Vector Column with createDataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, vector, apache-spark-sql

I can make a Spark DataFrame with a vector column with the `toDF` method.

```
val dataset = Seq((1.0, org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors.dense(0.0, 10.0, 0.5))).toDF("id", "userFeatures")

scala> dataset.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: double (nullable = false)
 |-- userFeatures: vector (nullable = true)


scala> dataset.schema
res5: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(id,DoubleType,false), StructField(userFeatures,org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7,true))
```

I'm not sure how to create a vector column with the `createDataFrame` method.  There isn't a `VectorType` type in [org.apache.spark.sql.types](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.package).

This doesn't work:

```
val rows = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
  List(
    Row(1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 2.0))
  )
)

val schema = List(
  StructField("id", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("features", new org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT, true)
)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  rows,
  StructType(schema)
)

df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

Comment: you already have a vector don't you? `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT`

Answer (score 2):

To create a Spark Vector Column with `createDataFrame`, you can use following code:

```
val rows = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
  List(
    Row(1.0, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.dense(1.0, 2.0))
  )
)

val schema = List(
  StructField("id", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("features", new org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT, true)
)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  rows,
  StructType(schema)
)

df.show()
+---+---------+
| id| features|
+---+---------+
|1.0|[1.0,2.0]|
+---+---------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: double (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

The actual issue was incompatible type `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors.dense` which is not a valid external type for schema of vector. So, we have to switch to `mllib` package instead of `ml` package.

I hope it helps!

**Note**: I am using Spark v2.3.0. Also, class `VectorUDT` in package `linalg` cannot be accessed in package `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg`.

**For reference** - https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib

Comment: Thanks @himanshuIIITian.  Is there any way to do this with the `org.apache.spark.ml` package?  Per the Spark documentation, the  spark.mllib package is in maintenance mode and all users are encouraged to use spark.ml.

Comment: @Powers As I have mentioned in **For Reference** section - `VectorUDT` is not accessbile outside of `org.apache.spark.ml` package.